# Designation "2-" in a technical drawing of a component

Tags: datasheet, mechanical, drawing

What does the encircled "2-" designate in the technical drawing below? Is it some standardized/common designation of something? "R" stands for the radius, and the numbers refers to the values in mm.

[image]

The picture is an excerpt from the 6th page of [this document](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/5051101892_sd.pdf). (I've added the red circles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that there are two objects with that dimension. The same shape exists on the right-hand side of the FFC without dimensions, so "2-" is letting you know that side is the same as the left.

Answer (score 4):

It is specifying that there are two of those areas sharing the same dimension: -

[image]